# Make all Pen points straight by default regardless of the previous point in the path

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to use Photohop's Pen tool to make a clean outline out of a sketch I made. I click and drag to create a curve, then release the mouse. Then I go to make my next point in the path... but I notice that this new point is affected by the curvature of the previous point. I want the new point to be rigid by default. This is what I mean:

1. Make a point
2. Make a second point, drag to make it a curve with the first point
3. Make a third point

[image]

See, the third point has a curve even though I didn't drag it. This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

Right now, I have to manually change the endpoint curve in the second point to be able to get a straight line between the second and third points. This is time consuming.

How can I make it so all new Pen points will be straight by default regardless of the previous point in the path?

Photoshop CC 2014. OSX Yosemite.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/drawing-pen-tools.html

Answer (score 4):

Hold ALT and press on the point you just placed, so for now the third one.
The next line will be straight.

[image]

Comment: If I do that, I cannot modify the curve between the first and second points on the go.

Comment: Sbaliyev, if you feel that I changed the answer for the worse, feel free to roll back the original answer.